# How to add Order By in Complex SQL queries when grabbing records using ASP

Tags: html, sql, asp-classic, sql-order-by, where-clause

I have a rather complex SQL statement that has multiple joins and I need to be able to add an order by in the end.

```
<%
Set rsProdInfo = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")

"
SELECT Company_Main.Company_Name,
       Company_Main.Company_Website,
       Practice_Areas.Practice_Area_ID,
       Practice_Areas.Practice_Area
FROM Practice_Areas
INNER JOIN ((Locations
             INNER JOIN (Company_Main
                         INNER JOIN Company_Location_CK ON Company_Main.Company_ID = Company_Location_CK.Company_ID) ON Locations.Location_ID = Company_Location_CK.Location_ID)
            INNER JOIN Company_Practice_CK ON Company_Main.Company_ID = Company_Practice_CK.Company_ID) ON Practice_Areas.Practice_Area_ID = Company_Practice_CK.Practice_Area_ID
WHERE Practice_Areas_CK.Practice_Area_ID=
" & intPractice_Area_ID

rsProdInfo.Open prodSQL, Conn
%>
```

I need to add an ORDER BY Company_main.Company_name after the WHERE statement but all I get is errors when I do this. Is there any way to get around this problem or is there another way to sort the data?

I tried adding this:

```
WHERE Practie_Areas_CK.Practice_Area_ID Order BY Company_main.Company_name =" & intPractice_Area_ID
```

The error I am getting is:

> Microsoft Access Database Engine error '80040e07' Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
>   /product.asp, line 45

Comment: What errors are you getting? I see no reason why adding an ORDER BY  clause to this statement would not work, please eloborate on what you tried and _what_ errors that yielded :)

Comment: This is a badly formulated question. Only post the code relevant to the problem. Here's a nice guide on how to post good questions: http://sscce.org/

Comment: I have tried it where it looked like this:  WHERE Practie_Areas_CK.Practice_Area_ID Order BY Company_main.Company_name =" & intPractice_Area_ID

Comment: the error I am getting is:

Comment: Microsoft Access Database Engine error '80040e07'

Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

/product.asp, line 45

Comment: Please post the actual code you're using. What you've posted obviously isn't it, because it's just a bunch of random text that would give an enormous syntax error right from the outset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole syntax is just wrong. Proper SQL syntax in your case would be:

```
"WHERE Practie_Areas_CK.Practice_Area_ID=" & intPractice_Area_ID & " Order BY Company_main.Company_name"
```

I strongly recommend you to visit some basic SQL tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it without the `ORDER BY`?

If you are still getting the error, something else might be wrong.